# easyXDM failing on IE8 with undefined object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, easyxdm

This script is working great in all browser but IE8, the error points me to the line 434 colum 75 telling me there is an undefined object.

Error log:

```
Messaggio: 'undefined' è nullo o non è un oggetto
Linea: 434
Carattere: 75
Codice: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:81/apitest/js/easyXDM.js
```

And this is the function on that line:

```
function testForNamePropertyBug(){
    var form = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("form")), input = form.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    input.name = IFRAME_PREFIX + "TEST" + channelId; // append channelId in order to avoid caching issues
    HAS_NAME_PROPERTY_BUG = input !== form.elements[input.name];
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

The exactly line 434 column 75 is:  *input*

EDIT:
[image]
LINK: http://postimg.org/image/n1ogavda3/

Comment: IE's line reporting is off by one, so it's probably document.body that is missing. Are you trying to use easyXDM before the body has been parsed, eg from a script in your HEAD?

Comment: no, this is how my html looks like: <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>API TEST EXAMPLE, PUNCTIS.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>API TEST LOCAL</h1>
        <div class="punctiscnt" data-actionid="punctis_api_test" >Content here?</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easyXDM.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/punctis.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: please let me know if you need the complete code

Comment: @SeanKinsey dont abandon me on this please! :)

Comment: No idea, but how about using F12 to debug?

Comment: @SeanKinsey please take a look of the edit i made

Comment: Sorry, but I've not heard of anyone else experiencing this issue, so I would start by creating a minimal example and then adding components from that. Most likely there's something else in your page that is causing this to happen.